# Drawing a line based on matrix coordinates

Tags: matlab

My teacher told us to use matlab to calculate the svd of a matrix. This is what I have done so far:

```
X=0:0.01:0.9; 
Y=5*X+randn(size(X));

A = [[X.'], [Y.']]

[U,S,V] = svd(A)

plot(X,Y,'ok')


L1 = [0 0]
L2 = [V(1,1) V(1,2)]

hold on
line (L1, L2)
hold off
```

I have generated some (almost) random points, Then I put them in a matrix and then I calculated the svd. The problem is that I cant visualize the `V` matrix. The line from (0,0) to (v[1,1] , v[1 2]) should be in the direction that the density of the data is the most. The V matrix looks fine here, When I draw the line from origin to (v[1,1] , v[1 2]) using pen and paper everything looks fine, But when I use `line` to create a line between these two points I dont get my desired line, the line looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want

```
 L1 = [0 V(1,1)]
 L2 = [0 V(1,2)]
```

What you called `L1` here are the x coordinates and `L2` are the y coordinates.  To have your first point be the origin, that's a 0 in the first position in both arrays.  Likewise to have the matrix define the second point, you need the matrix elements in the second position in both arrays.